# code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR', errno: 1064, sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, api

I'm making an API and although all the syntax and the query fired is correct but it is showing me

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'load' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'select * from load'
```

My code

```
Router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    mysqlConnection.query("select * from load",(err,rows,fields)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.send(rows);
        }else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
});
```

'load' is the table name in my MySQL database and I want to fetch everything from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOAD is a reserved word in MySQL, as part of [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) or [LOAD XML](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-xml.html). If you want to use 'load' as a table name you'll have to quote it with backticks:

```
select * from `load`
```